# Postgres Window Function Syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Why does the following query:

`select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC) as rownum FROM users where rownum < 20;`

produce the following error?

`ERROR:  column "rownum" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d ORDER BY time DESC) as rownum FROM users where rownum < 2...`

How can I structure this query so that I get the first 20 items, as defined by my window function?

`user_id` and `time` are both defined columns on `users`.

Comment: Obviously, I'm not trying to just fetch the top 20 rows of `users`. I've simplified my query to more clearly illustrate the syntax error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would work like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC) AS rownum
   FROM   users
   ) x
WHERE  rownum < 20;
```

The point here is the sequence of events. Window functions are applied after the `WHERE` clause. Therefore `rownum` is not visible, yet. You have to put it into a subquery or CTE and apply the `WHERE` clause on `rownum` in the next query level.

[Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html):

> Window functions are permitted only in the `SELECT` list and the `ORDER BY`
>   clause of the query. They are forbidden elsewhere, such as in `GROUP BY`, 
>   `HAVING` and `WHERE` clauses. This is because they logically execute
>   after the processing of those clauses. Also, window functions execute
>   after regular aggregate functions. This means it is valid to include
>   an aggregate function call in the arguments of a window function, but
>   not vice versa.

Comment: [Here](http://wwwlgis.informatik.uni-kl.de/cms/fileadmin/courses/SS2014/Neuere_Entwicklungen/Chapter_6_-_Windows_and_Query_Functions_in_SQL.pdf#page=19) you can see that Window Functions are processed after filtering the WHERE predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `where` clause executes before the select so it does not know about that alias yet. Do it like this:

```
select *
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC) as rownum 
    FROM users 
) s
where rownum < 20;
```